# Scope of variables for a class inside a method in python

Tags: python, inheritance, scope

I am not able to understand the scope of few variables and why python is throwing an error while trying to do few things inside a class that is defined a method

Let me start with a basic example which works and then move on to few examples which work and which doesn't. I have an idea about what is working and sometimes what is not. But I feel that I lack an understanding the scope in this case (class inside a method)

First an example which works

**Case 1:**

```
def foo_method(a, b, c):
    return b, c, a

def bar_method(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    class BarClass:

        a_ = a + 1
        b_ = b + 1
        c_ = c + 1

        b_, c_, a_ = foo_method(a, b, c)

    return BarClass()
```

When I try to run the above code it works i.e 
`temp = bar_method()` works with out any issue

**Case 2:**

```
def foo_method(a, b, c):
    return b, c, a

def bar_method(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    class BarClass:

        a_ = a + 1
        b_ = b + 1
        c_ = c + 1

        b, c, a = foo_method(a, b, c)

    return BarClass()
```

Case 2 doesnt work i.e `temp = bar_method()` throws the error `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

**Case 3:**

```
def foo_method(a, b, c):
    return b, c, a

def bar_method(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    class BarClass:

        a = a + 1
        b = b + 1
        c = c + 1

    return BarClass()
```

Case 3 doesnt work i.e `temp = bar_method()` throws the error `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

**Case 4**

```
def foo_method(a, b, c):
    return b, c, a

def bar_method(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    class BarClass:

        a_ = a + 1
        b_ = b + 1
        c_ = c + 1

        a_ = a_ + 1

        b_, c_, a_ = foo_method(a_, b_, c_)

    return BarClass()
```

Case 4 works.

I got confused as to why certain operations are working and why others aren't. Can anyone shed some explanation on what I am not able to comprehend here. It seems like I can't make any modifications to the variables defined in the `bar_method`

Comment: Thanks for the link. The question seems similar. I couldn't see an explanation of it can't be modified in that thread

Comment: Note that you could slim down your examples since `b` and `c` are redundant. Also note in case 1, `a_`, `b_`, and `c_` are immediately overwritten.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, you don't want to modify the nonlocals, just access them. I'll remove the duplicate flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignments in the classes:

```
#case 2
b, c, a = ...

#case 3
a = ...
b = ...
c = ...
```

make those names local to the class's scope so the names on the right-hand-side of the assignment are interpreted as the local scope names. Which haven't been evaluated yet.
<sub>(that might not have been said well, feel free to improve wording)</sub>

---

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23471004/2823755
https://stackoverflow.com/a/370380/2823755

---

From [4. Execution model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#execution-model):
4.1. Structure of a program

> A Python program is constructed from code blocks. A block is a piece
>   of Python program text that is executed as a unit. The following are
>   blocks: a module, a function body, and a class definition.

4.2.1 Binding of names discusses name binding by assignment within code blocks.

In 4.2.2. Resolution of names, the 4th paragraph states:

> If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all
>   uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the
>   current block.

I cannot find a reference yet but the name binding is occurring before the evaluations.
<sub>(my assumption -maybe someone will clarify)</sub>

---

An finally (?) from the Programming FAQ
[Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Comment: Very interesting. The way I have learned variable assignment is that python evaluates the portion on the right and then assigns to the variable on the left

Comment: @RTM See my edit